# How to run string as function inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

An example of this question is like this

```
var bar = (function(){

   function foo(){
      alert("foo");
   }

   function test(){
     var f = "foo";

     // I want to run  f() to run the function foo
   }
})();
```

If the function is in the global scope I can run it using `window["foo"]()` or if namespaced `window["namespace"]["foo"]()` but how can I run it inside like the example? I don't want to use `eval()`.

A much clear example of what I want is like this:

```
var fns = ['a','b','c'],
    bar = (function(){

      function a(){
          alert("a");          
      }

      function b(){
          alert("b");          
      }

      function c(){
          alert("c");          
      }

      function test(array){
         for(var i;i<array.length;i++){
            //I want to run the functions that is on the array
            // something like window[array[i]]() if function is in the global scope

         }
       }

      return {
         test : test
      }
    })();

    bar.test(fns);
```

Comment: You cannot do that. There's no way to generate a dynamic indirect reference to a local symbol.

Comment: Why don't you just call `foo()`?

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose? Maybe you should consider an object of strings to functions?

Comment: well, there's also `setTimeout`

Comment: And all of the other aliases for `eval`

Comment: `eval` won't make `f()` in JS run `foo`, though.

Comment: What's wrong with my comment, and the later answer, of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a local object to reference the function, then access its property as you would with your `window` example.

```js
var bar = (function(){

   function foo(){
      alert("foo");
   }

   var obj = {
     foo: foo
   };

   function test(){
     var f = obj["foo"];
     f();
   }
  
   test();
})();
```

That's as close as you're going to get in a local scope without using `eval`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the object OR fn with this operator and make it an function with new constructor.

Creating an object.

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lyrz6rm/6/

```
var bar = {
foo: function(){
      alert("foo");
   },
test: function(){
     var f = "foo";
         return f;
   }
}
bar["foo"]();
console.log(bar["test"]());
```

Another alternate way is to define the function as with constructor and little modification.

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lyrz6rm/4/

```
   var bar = function(){
this.foo = function(){
      alert("foo");
   };
this.test = function(){
     var f = "foo";
            return f;
     // I want to run  f() to run the function foo
   }
this.test2 = {
        f: "foo"
    }
}
var f = new bar();
f["foo"]();
console.log(f.test());
console.log(f.test2.f);
```

Comment: The first example doesn't use `new`; I'm not sure what you're trying to say in your opening sentence. (And `test` doesn't make much sense, why wouldn't you just return `"foo"`?)

Comment: missed OR... while typing. You cannot return multiple functions unless you create an object.

Comment: Neither of your examples executes the function based on its name as the op wants.

Comment: ? He need to use the fiddle as per his usage. What he needs is there... please look at both fidles again

Comment: Your first console.log simply calls a method with the hard-wired name `test`. Your second console.log simply outputs a sub-property of a property on the object.

Comment: yes its to show it works. he can use it as per he wants. His intent is incomplete.

Comment: @Gary Right, but you say "make it an function with new constructor" but there's no constructor or anything, it's just an immediate object. My point about the `test` function was that there's no reason to use a local variable if you're just going to return it immediately.

Comment: new fn() operator is what you want to look at since with `this` usage the fn becomes a constructor fn. Second for your question, what you will do by your code is create a closure that cannot be referenced. You will have to manipulate the function or change your code style a little for what you want to achieve. There are ways to convert a string to a function but its a different thing when you have a function within function; more that cannot be referenced even as an object. Not sure if that is what you were refering to. return immediately is not clear since usage is outside the function.